# Firebase In-App Messaging really works on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I'm having difficulty using In-App Messaging and I do not know how to solve this problem.

I created a campaign and sent a test to a device, and this test never succeeds. Today I was surprised by the message being displayed from a test I had done three days ago.

I've read and reread all of the In-App Messaging documentation and all the steps were followed correctly, but I've never been able to make it work.

After all, does In-App Messaging work on iOS or is it just a proposal to maybe work in the future (if it works)? Honestly it's pretty frustrating something so simple does not work.

Comment: What does your code look like? What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: @ZGski I don't have any code, because from what I read in the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started) you only need to install the Pod's dependencies, configure the Firebase (which is already configured, because I use other Firebase features).

Comment: Just went through the docs and it works for me.

Comment: I have similar problems now and I am trying to make it work with trial and error.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65655110/why-are-my-firebase-in-app-messages-unreliable-in-production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be running into a [bug](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2981) that was recently introduced.  The fix will be available in the upcoming Firebase 6.1.0 release.

In the meantime, you could get the functionality back by installing to Firebase 5.17.0 or earlier, along with FirebaseInAppMessaging 0.12.2 or earlier.