# Why are my Firebase In-app messages unreliable in production?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

In-app messages work well in test mode, but seem to be very unreliable in production. I made campaigns with "Modals" as the message layout. The simplest possible messages, without any pictures. If I set countries as the targets, no messages seem to be shown in the target countries.

I have 2 campaigns without any country targets and those messages get shown, but still just sometimes. The first of these campaigns informs the user they have an opportunity to reach Level 1.
The message get shown about 50% of the times it should be shown (once per device). Sometimes the message get shown so quickly that it just flashes by, so it is impossible to read the text. It closes before the user closes it. The second of these campaigns inform the user when they have reached Level 1.  It is the same result as described above here.

My calls to logEvent are from methods, which are directly called from the onresume method in the Main activity of the app. They are called according to certain conditions, not every time onresume is called. My calls look for instance like this:

FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).logEvent("gyro_access", Bundle.EMPTY);

What can be done to make the In-app messages work in a reliable way in production?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work now. I used this method instead to trigger the messages:

FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().triggerEvent()

I also updated Gradle, so the latest version of com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display was used.

So the solution to my problem was either using the triggerEvent-method or updating Gradle.

Comment: Hey @Mobile Visuals, It's seems like there is still a problem. According to Firebase you don't need to create triggerEvent() in order to get in-app notifications. It should be a ready-to-go service. In addition, if it's working only "50% of the times" on on_foreground events (default firebase event when users open the app) then it's broken. I know that firebase analytics are very slow, it takes them a lot of time to reach analytics. In-app messaging is based on app events, so I assume that that is the reason of your problem - very slow analytics. I'm struggling the same problem.

Comment: @genericUser I'm facing the same problem. Works in "Test on device" but not working in production application. Any solution?

Comment: I have implemented my own in-app messaging mechanizem, so I didn't test Firebase in-app messaging since then. But please comment here for any news! I would like to use that feature if it's reliable.

Comment: I was so dissapointed with  in-app messaging, so I have not done anything with it since February. I will let you know when I give it a new try!